# How to get current post id when writing raw sql query in Flask SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written a raw SQL query to display the list of users who have liked a post, but the query returns a list of users who have liked not just the current post but other posts too.

Here is the route I have written

```
@app.route('/like/<int:post_id>/viewLikes')
@login_required
def viewLikers(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    result = db.engine.execute("Select username from user, PostLike, Post where user.id=PostLike.users_id and PostLike.post_id=post.id")
    return render_template('viewLikes.html', likers=result)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add one more condition to your query:

```
post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
sql = "Select username from user, PostLike, Post where user.id=PostLike.users_id and PostLike.post_id=post.id and PostLike.post_id = :pid"
result = db.engine.execute(sql, {'pid': post} )
```

Comment: Happy to help :)